# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to identify an element (a textbox) using Selenium Webdriver with Java. But, it is giving me the **Unable to Locate Element Exception**. The id of the element is unchanged. Here's the HTML code:

```
<div>
    <table id="searchIdText">
        <tbody>
            <tr id="searchIdText-inputRow">
                <td id="searchIdText-labelCell"><label
                    id="searchIdText-labelEl"> Search By Id <span
                        role="separator">:</span>
                </label></td>
                <td id="searchIdText-bodyEl"><input id="searchIdText-inputEl"
                    type="text" autocomplete="off" name="searchIdText-inputEl" size="1"
                    role="textbox" style="width: 100%; height: 20px;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The element that I want is the textbox with the id **searchIdText-inputEl**. I have tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchIdText-inputEl']"));

driver.findElement(By.name("searchIdText-inputEl"))`
```

as well as :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("searchIdText-inputEl"));
```

But none of them are working. I have tried waits and `Thread.sleep` too. None of them are working. Also, changing the HTML code is not an option here. All suggestions apart from these are welcome.Thanks!

The Java code snippet is as follows. As a desperate measure, I added both Explicit Wait and Thread.sleep together after both of them failed to give me the result individually. But, it still was of no use.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement element = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.get(url);
Thread.sleep(60000);
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchIdText-inputEl']"));
element.sendKeys("ABC");
```

Comment: Is the element visible as soon as the page loads? Are you able to post your current Java code just to give a bit more context?

Comment: Edited and added the Java code snippet.

Comment: Thanks, and can you see the page loading, is the element visible?

Comment: Yes. The element is visible and the page does load fully. I tried to print the page title just to make sure that the driver handle is in the correct tab. Even that was printed correctly.

Comment: The element isn't in a separate frame on the page is it?

Comment: No. There are no frames used. There is however a lot of divs and table tags in between the body tag and the start of this div.

Comment: I would suggest that the best way to find the element is `By.id` as there's no chance of getting the xpath wrong then. Can you give that another go, is that definitely not working?

Comment: I'm positive. And that's what is bugging me the most. :(

Comment: Is this a public web page? It's getting hard to debug without having access to the page

Comment: No. It isn't. It's a custom app build in Rally for my organization.

Comment: Try finding some other elements on the page, see if there's an issue with the page overall, or just this element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118992/discussion-between-abhineet-kumar-and-josh).

Comment: @AbhineetKumar for make sure there is no frame need to execute `document.getElementsByTagName("frame")` and `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")` in your browser console and let us know the result..:)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Turns out, there was an iFrame, which was hidden and somehow the control was transferred to that iFrame upon page load. I switched it and now it works fine. :)

Comment: This should be marked as answered as it comes-up under "Unanswered Questions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there was an iFrame, which was hidden and somehow the control was transferred to that iFrame upon page load. I switched it and now it works fine.